# Looking for automated software that can listen to a audio line and records a mp3 file to then send via email

Tags: audio

Listening for an Audio Signal on a line in or via microphone. When detected, record audio file.
When finished send audio mp3 file to email source.

Anyone know of a solution out there in the marketplace or can code this please advise. I will pay.
Thank you

Comment: This is easy. You just need a script (could be written in Javascript) that will do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is called `Sound detection` or `Microphone monitoring` software.  but Stackoverflow is not a place to recommend specific software.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, where might be a good place to ask?